# Readline and threading

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I run the code below, and when I use queue.qsize() after I run it, there are still 450,000 or so items in the queue, implying most lines of the text file were not read. Any idea what is going on here?

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

lines = 660918 #int(str.split(os.popen('wc -l HGDP_FinalReport_Forward.txt').read())[0]) -1
queue = Queue()
File = 'HGDP_FinalReport_Forward.txt'
num_threads =10
short_file = open(File)

class worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        while True:           
            try:           
                self.queue.get()     
                i  = short_file.readline()
                self.queue.task_done() #signal to the queue that the task is done
            except:               
                break

## This is where I should make the call to the threads

def main():
    for i in range(num_threads):
        worker(queue).start()
    queue.join()


    for i in range(lines): # put the range of the number of lines in the .txt file
        queue.put(i)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do here, but if each line can be processed independently, `multiprocessing` is a much simpler choice that will take care of all the synchronization for you. An added bonus is that you don't have to know the number of lines in advance.

Basically,

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)

def process(line):
    return len(line) #or whatever

with open(path) as lines:
    results = pool.map(process, lines)
```

Or, if you're just trying to get some kind of aggregate result from the lines, you can use `reduce` to lower memory usage.

```
import operator
with open(path) as lines:
    result = reduce(operator.add, pool.map(process, lines))
```

Comment: Ya, this is just a dumbed down version of my program. I didn't want to post everything and cloud the problem.

Comment: don't both of these require you to open the entire file being used? If that's the case it does not work for me because the file is too large. I keep hitting memory errors, which is why I was using readline.

Comment: No, pool.map is lazy, so it will take lines from the file generator as needed. You can also specify the chunksize (number of lines at a time) as the third parameter. However, it RETURNS a list, so if the results are also too large to fit in memory, then you can also use multiprocessing.Pool.imap, which returns an iterator. In general if you wanted to use the second solution (with reduce), you'd want to pair it with imap.

The docs: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1):

so I tried doing this but I am getting a bit confused because I need to pass a single line each time, and that isn't what the code seems to be doing

```
import multiprocessing as mp

File = 'HGDP_FinalReport_Forward.txt'
#short_file = open(File)
test = []

def pro(temp_line):
    temp_line = temp_line.strip().split()
    return len(temp_line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("HGDP_FinalReport_Forward.txt") as lines:
        pool = mp.Pool(processes = 10)
        t = pool.map(pro,lines)
```